# Browsers are ignoring CSS Selector?

Tags: css

I've got this selector code:

```
#ajax_hits_counter_popular_posts_widget-2.widget li img {
// Give the thumbs in the widget some style
border-radius: 5px;
margin-right: 10px;
border: 4px solid #353434 !important;
}
```

Everything is rendering properly except for the `border: 4px solid #353434 !important;`

When viewing in either Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, the border: property doesn't even show up at all, while the others do.

If I manually type the same exact code into Firebug or Chrome tools, it works fine.

Live is here (it's the "Top Posts" thumbnail widget at the bottom right): [Meanwhile, In America](http://meanwhileinamerica.com)

Anyone know why?

Comment: Without seeing the related HTML no one can say if your selector is correct.

Comment: That's why I included the live link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// Give the thumbs in the widget some style
```

is invalid in CSS. The browser seems to ignore the following property, as you can see in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/HHA39/2/). If you remove the "comment" [it works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/HHA39/3/). (On your page, the `border` declaration directly follows the "comment", unlike in the CSS posted here)

Comments in CSS have to be enclosed in `/* ... */`.

---

As [tim.baker mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20688970/218196), you have have to use `border` instead of `border-style`.

Comment: Ah haaaa! I never knew that! that did it, thanks a mil @Felix Kling.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your CSS it seams as though you have used

```
border-style: 4px solid #353434 !important;
```

Using purely

```
border: 4px solid #353434;
```

Should work

Comment: SO is very competitive I think :)

Comment: the strange thing is, if I remove `!important`, then the border-radius property is now ignored? lol

Comment: Good catch, though it's not enough to make it work ;)

Comment: You're right. While bullfighting with it I was trying different things, out of frustration, lol.